# Class instance of two variables

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and created this class

```
class Printable a where 
    toString :: a -> String
```

And two of its instances

```
instance Printable Bool where
    toString x | x == True = "true"
               | x == False  = "false" 

instance Printable () where
    toString x = "unit type"
```

They work just fine, and now I want to create an instance that would take two parameters, but I'm having troubles. What I created so far is

```
instance (Printable a, Printable b) => Printable (a, b) where
    toString x | fst x == True = "(true,unit type)"
```

But now I get the error

> Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Bool’

which is reasonable, but when I replace `a` with `Bool` I also get an error. How can I make it work in the first place, and can I restrict the types for `a` and `b` - for example, what if I want `a` to always be `Bool` and `b` to always be ()?

Comment: Please include error any error messages you get in your question.  (In this case, I'm pretty sure the error message tells you *exactly* how to fix it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrote an instance where you write that for a tuple `(a, b)`, the tuple is `Printable` in case the items `a` and `b` are `Printable`. But that does *not* mean that `a` or `b` are `Bool`s, or units.

You may think that - like in many languages - the `(==)` operator works on any two types, but in Haskell `(==)` has type `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, so it is a function where the left and the right operand have the *same* type. So we can not use `x == True`, unless `x` is a `Bool`.

We do not need these guards. What we need to do is *call* the `toString` function of the operands, so:

```
instance (Printable a, Printable b) => Printable (a, b) where
    toString (x,y) = "(" ++ toString x ++ "," ++ toString y ++ ")"
```

We can also replace `[x] ++` with `x : ...` so we can rewrite it to:

```
instance (Printable a, Printable b) => Printable (a, b) where
    toString (x,y) = '(' :  toString x ++ ',' : toString y ++ ")"
```

**EDIT**: in case you want `a` to be always a `Bool`, you can write:

```
instance Printable b => Printable (Bool, b) where
    toString (x,y) = '(' :  toString x ++ ',' : toString y ++ ")"
```

You can of course now add guards, pattern matching, or some other method to discriminate between `x == True` and `x == False`, but I advice you not to do this, since this violates the DRY principle: **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i cannot assume that, but is there a way to indicate that a is always a Bool in class instance?

Comment: `()` isn't really an empty tuple.

Answer (score 4):

Just because `a` has a `Printable` instance doesn't mean you can assume `a ~ Bool`, so `x == True` fails.

You should be using pattern matching instead of equality, though, which would sidestep the issue.

```
class Printable a where 
    toString :: a -> String

instance Printable Bool where
    toString True = "true"
    toString False = "false"

instance Printable () where
    toString () = "unit type"
```

Your tuple instance should then make use of the fact that `a` and `b` are both `Printable`. You only need to pattern-match on the constructor, not the individual components.

```
instance (Printable a, Printable b) => Printable (a, b) where
    toString (x, y)  = "(" ++ toString x ++ "," ++ toString y ++ ")"
```